# How do I setup messaging and session middleware in a Django RequestFactory during unit testing

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I have a function I need to test which takes a request as its argument. It is not exposed as a view by URL so I cannot test it with the test client.

I need to pass a request object to it, and the request object needs to have the messaging middleware enabled because messaging middleware is used in the function.

I am using the RequestFactory to create my request. The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/advanced/#django.test.client.RequestFactory) says:

> It does not support middleware. Session and authentication attributes must be supplied by the test itself if required for the view to function properly.

**How do I setup the messaging middleware with the RequestFactory?** I think I will also need the session middleware to make the messaging middleware work

This is the error my test currently produces when using the vanilla RequestFactory.

```
MessageFailure: You cannot add messages without installing django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware
```

This is my function under test, in case it helps with understanding this problem:

```
from django.contrib import messages as django_messages

def store_to_request(self, request):
        """
        Place all the messages stored in this class into message storage in
        the request object supplied.
        :param request: The request object to which we should store all the messages
        :return: Does not return anything
        """
        for message in self._messages:
            django_messages.add_message(request, message.level, message.message, message.extra_tags,
                                    message.fail_silently)
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This issue [was raised](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17971), so as there said, you can fix your unit tests using that code:

```
from django.contrib.messages.storage.fallback import FallbackStorage
setattr(request, 'session', 'session')
messages = FallbackStorage(request)
setattr(request, '_messages', messages)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need to test the behaviour of the request object itself you could mock the request using the [mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/) library instead of RequestFactory e.g:

```
import mock

request = mock.MagicMock()

# Call your function using the mocked request
store_to_request(request)
```

Comment: This is a nice answer and I am going to use it in my testing along with mock call_args. Unfortunately it doesn't allow me to call django.contrib.messages.get_messages(request) on the mocked request object to see which messages were saved in the request. I want to test the output messages to ensure they were saved correctly.

Comment: note that you can set attributes and functions on your mocked request to achieve the behaviour you need.

Comment: The request object is passed in as an argument to the add_messages function from the message middleware. (you can see above in my code snippet). This makes it very difficult to test by simply adding attributes. It needs support functions added to work correctly

Answer (score 2):

An effictively equivalent method to Danag's anwer would be to pass the request object through the process_request methods of the session and message middlewares (in that order) before passing it to the view/function:

```
from django.contrib.sessions.middleware import SessionMiddleware
from django.contrib.messages.middleware import MessageMiddleware

request = request_factory.get()
sm = SessionMiddleware()
sm.process_request(request)
mm = MessageMiddleware()
mm.process_request(request)
```

You can do the above in a method for convenience:

```
class MessageDependentTests(TestCase):
    
    def setUp(self):
        self.rf = RequestFactory()
        self.sm = SessionMiddleware()
        self.mm = MessageMiddleware()
        return super().setUp()
        
    def prepare_request(self, request):
        self.sm.process_request(request)
        self.mm.process_request(request)

    def test_something(self):
        request = self.rf.get('/')
        self.prepare_request(request)
        response = my_view(request)
        # test response below
```

Comment: for those needing to test the generated user messages, please refer to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76850274/12505071