# Django messages middleware issue while testing post request

Tags: python, django, testing, pytest

I'm trying to test an UpdateView that adds a message to the redirected success page. It seems my issue comes from `messages` because of pytest returns:

> django.contrib.messages.api.MessageFailure: You cannot add messages without installing django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware

My test code is:

```py
def test_authenticated_staff(self, rf):
    langues = LanguageCatalog.objects.create(
        lang_src='wz',
        lang_dest='en',
        percent='4'
    )
    req = rf.get(reverse("dashboard.staff:lang-update", kwargs={'pk': langues.pk}))
    data = {'lang_src': 'it',
            'lang_dest': 'en',
            'percent': '34'}
    req = rf.post(reverse(
        "dashboard.staff:lang-update", kwargs={'pk': langues.pk}), data=data)
    req.user = UserFactory()
    resp = views.LangUpdateView.as_view()(req, pk=langues.pk)
```

I precise that the `MessageMiddleware` is present in `MIDDLEWARE` settings. I use `Django==2.0.13`.

Comment: Check if you have django.contrib.messages in INSTALLED_APPS and django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware in MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES.

Comment: As said in my post, and unfortunately, it is installed. I did as suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41033222/django-1-9-unittest-error-for-messages-but-i-dont-see-the-error-for-1-10-4-and-1 with no success.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23861157/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found the solution. In order to test a such request, you need first to annotate it with a session and then a message. Actually it means to add these lines:

```py
from django.contrib.messages.middleware import MessageMiddleware
from django.contrib.sessions.middleware import SessionMiddleware

# in your test method:
"""Annotate a request object with a session"""
middleware = SessionMiddleware()
middleware.process_request(req)
req.session.save()

"""Annotate a request object with a messages"""
middleware = MessageMiddleware()
middleware.process_request(req)
req.session.save()

# and then (in my case)
resp = views.LangUpdateView.as_view()(req, pk=langues.pk)
```

Comment: When you use `RequestFactory`, only the view runs, not the middleware. If you use the [request client](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/tools/#default-test-client), then the middleware will run and you won't have to manually annotate the request object.

Comment: I didn't use ```client``` because I didn't manage to setup a ```user``` with ```is_staff``` == True... I definitely should study that point. Thanks !

Comment: Great reply, together with context manager suggested by @Andrzej Bistram, 10/10, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You can also move manual request annotation int a separate context manager that can be reused within multiple tests, the code would look like this then:

```py
import contextlib

from django.contrib.messages.middleware import MessageMiddleware
from django.contrib.sessions.middleware import SessionMiddleware


@contextlib.contextmanager
def middleware(request):
    """Annotate a request object with a session"""
    middleware = SessionMiddleware()
    middleware.process_request(request)
    request.session.save()

    """Annotate a request object with a messages"""
    middleware = MessageMiddleware()
    middleware.process_request(request)
    request.session.save()
    yield request


def test_authenticated_staff(self, rf):
    langues = LanguageCatalog.objects.create(
        lang_src='wz',
        lang_dest='en',
        percent='4'
    )
    req = rf.get(reverse("dashboard.staff:lang-update", kwargs={'pk': langues.pk}))
    data = {'lang_src': 'it',
            'lang_dest': 'en',
            'percent': '34'}
    req = rf.post(reverse("dashboard.staff:lang-update", kwargs={'pk': langues.pk}), data=data)
    req.user = UserFactory()
    with middleware(req):  # << !
        resp = views.LangUpdateView.as_view()(req, pk=langues.pk)
```

Answer (score 0):

For those that encounter this issue after some years, and getting exceptions because of the "get_response must be provided.":

@EmilioConte solution still works, just add a simple lambda to the constructor:
'SessionMiddleware(get_response=lambda request: None)'

Or:

```
def process_request_middleware(self, request: WSGIRequest) -> WSGIRequest:
        """ helper method: add messages and session data to an WSGI request"""
        from django.contrib.sessions.middleware import SessionMiddleware
        sessionMiddleware = SessionMiddleware(get_response=lambda request: None)
        sessionMiddleware.process_request(request)
        request.session.save()

        from django.contrib.messages.middleware import MessageMiddleware
        messageMiddleware = MessageMiddleware(get_response=lambda request: None)
        messageMiddleware.process_request(request)
        request.session.save()

        return request
```