# Testing messages when using RequestFactory()

Tags: python, django, django-forms, mocking, django-testing

I am testing a class based view using mock to raise an exception.
On exception, a message should be created and then a redirect executed.
Whilst I am able to test that the redirect has been executed, I am unable as yet to retrieve the message to be able to verify it.

**view**

```
CustomUser = get_user_model()

class SignUpView(FormView):
    template_name = 'accounts/signup.html'
    form_class = SignUpForm

    def form_valid(self, form):

        try:
            self.user = CustomUser.objects.filter(email=form.cleaned_data['email']).first()

            if not self.user:

                self.user = CustomUser.objects.create_user(email=form.cleaned_data['email'],
                                                           full_name=form.cleaned_data['full_name'],
                                                           password=form.cleaned_data['password'],
                                                           is_verified=False
                                                           )
            else:
                if self.user.is_verified:

                    self.send_reminder()

                    return super().form_valid(form)

            self.send_code()
        except:
            messages.error(self.request, _('Something went wrong, please try to register again'))
            return redirect(reverse('accounts:signup'))

        return super().form_valid(form)
```

My test so far:

```
class SignUpViewTest(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.factory = RequestFactory()

    def test_database_fail(self):
        with patch.object(CustomUserManager, 'create_user') as mock_method:
            mock_method.side_effect = Exception(ValueError)

            view = SignUpView.as_view()
            url = reverse('accounts:signup')
            data = {'email': 'test@test.com', 'full_name': 'Test Tester', 'password': 'Abnm1234'}
            request = self.factory.post(url, data)
            setattr(request, 'session', 'session')
            messages = FallbackStorage(request)
            request._messages = messages

            response = view(request)

            self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
            self.assertEqual(response.url, '/accounts/signup/')
```

My question is, how do I retrieve the message so that I can make an assertEqual against the message: 'Something went wrong, please try to register again'?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55843504, https://stackoverflow.com/q/23861157

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging a little deeper the message(s) can be found here:

```
request._messages._queued_messages[0]
```

And therefore the assertEqual would be:

```
self.assertEqual(str(request._messages._queued_messages[0]), 'Something went wrong, please try to register again')
```

Answer (score 1):

> After digging a little deeper the message(s) can be found here: `request._messages._queued_messages[0]` And therefore the
> assertEqual would be: `self.assertEqual(str(request._messages._queued_messages[0]), 'Something went wrong, please try to register again')`

It seemed a bit hacky, and after a few hours of research, I found a slightly more robust way to achieve a way to test user messages generated by a view (nb of messages, presence of some string inside last generated/only message, presence on specific strings in each generated messages):

```
from django.contrib.messages import get_messages

self.assertEqual(len(get_messages(request)), expected_nb_messages)


user_messages_sent = [str(i) for i in get_messages(request)] 
# the resulting BaseStorage class has an iterator method
# string conversion is needed to access to the actual text of the Message object 
           
if type(text_to_test_in_message)==dict:
   for k,v in text_to_test_in_message.items():
       self.assertIn(v, user_messages_sent[k])
   else:
       self.assertIn(text_to_test_in_message, user_messages_sent[-1])
```